# Postgres constant 30% CPU usage

Tags: windows, postgresql, centos, database-migration

I recently migrated my Postgres database from Windows to CentOS 6.7.
On Windows the database never used much CPU, but on Linux I see it using a constant ~30% CPU (using top). (4 core on machine)

Anyone know if this is normally, or why it would be doing this?
The application seems to run fine, and as fast or faster than Windows.

Note, it is a big database, 100gb+ data, 1000+ databases.

I tried using Pgadmin to monitor the server status, but the server status hangs, and fails to run, error "the log_filename parameter must be equal"

Comment: Did you check running queries? select * from pg_stat_activity where state <> 'idle' . Probably is some autovacuum running...

Comment: What PostgreSQL processes are shown in `top`? What are their command lines? Run it as `top -c` to see.

Comment: top -c gives --> 28378 postgres  20   0 1735m  85m 6508 R 18.3  1.1   2233:11 postgres: autovacuum launcher process

Comment: So I assume that means it is auto vacuum, is it expected to take constant 30% of CPU (30% of 1 core --> 8% total)

Comment: [Maybe a better palce to ask](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6):

With 1000 databases I expect vacuum workers and stats collector to spend a lot of time checking about what needs maintenance.

I suggest you to do two things

- raise the `autovacuum_naptime` parameter to reduce the frequency of checks
- put the `stats_temp_directory` on a ramdisk

You probably also set a high `max_connections` limit to allow your clients to use those high number of databases and this is another probable source of CPU load, due to the high number of 'slots' to be checked every time a backend has to synchronize with the others.

Comment: any idea why the same database on windows did not use any cpu?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL you were using on Windows? What you are using now? Was the configuration of PostgreSQL exactly the same? Windows is very different form Linux in the way it handles memory and disks, so if the configuration you are using on CentOS is the same you had on Windows it may be not appropriate.

Comment: @James  With default settings on windows, in my hands, the system becomes essentially unusable long before it reaches 1000 databases.  Are you sure you didn't have autovac turned off or autovacuum_naptime increased on the Windows server?

Comment: both machines use the same settings, and have autovac running, both run fine with 1000 dbs, just linux has the extra cpu

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for increasing server loads.

1. If you are looking for query level loads on server then you should match a specific Postgres backend ID to a system process ID using the pg_stat_activity system table.

> SELECT pid, datname, usename, query FROM pg_stat_activity;

Once you know what queries are running you can investigate further (EXPLAIN/EXPLAIN ANALYZE; check locks, etc.)

2. You may have lock contention issues, probably due to very high **max_connections**. Consider lowering max_connections and using a connection pooler if this is the case. But that can increase turn around time for clients connections.
3. Might be Windows System blocking connections and not allowing to use system. And now Linus allowing its connections to use CPU and perform faster. :P

Also worth read:

1. [How to monitor PostgreSQL](http://blog.pandorafms.org/how-to-monitor-postgress/)
2. [Monitoring CPU and memory usage from Postgres](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2015/02/19/1/monitoring-cpu-memory-usage-from-postgres)